# C++ integer factorization library

Tags: c++, math

I've firstly asked this question on SO, because I didn't know that such questions are off-topic there.

During porting my Python's prototype to C++ because of performance issues, I've faced with problem of finding good library for factorization (actually, finding all (not only prime) divisors of number).

Currently I'm using [SymPy's `divisors` function](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.factor_.divisors) and it would be awesome if something similar for C++ exists. I can't just port SymPy's implementation, as it's rather complicated (not just one function).

All my numbers are 64-bit, so, I'm not considering GMP-based solutions.